# Element is not centering with text-align: center added

Tags: html, css, center

I have a simple section I am using under my footer. In my media query 640px or less, the two lines will not center with `text-align: center` added. I have also tried `margin: 0 auto`, but that also did not work for me.

Why are these two paragraphs not centering? This is so simple, but I am just missing something.

```css
#copyright {
 width: 100%;
 /*padding: 10px 10%;*/
 color: #999999;
 background: #1B1B1B;
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 clear: both;
}
#copyright a {
 color: #999999;
}
#copyright_left {
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 10%;
}
#copyright_right {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 10%;
}

/*----------------------------------------------PHONE MEDIA QUERY 640--------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
/*---Copy Right ---*/
#copyright {
 font-size: .9em;
  text-align: center;
}
#copyright_left {
 text-align: center;
}
#copyright_right {
 text-align: center;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="copyright">
    <p id="copyright_left">&copy; 2016 -All Rights Reserved- <a href="index.php">EquipmentInsider.com</a></p>
    <p id="copyright_right"><a href="About-us.php">About Us</a> | <a href="Contact-us.php">Contact</a> | <a href="Terms-of-Agreement.php">Terms of Agreement</a></p>

    <br class="clear" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have given float in your main css so in responsive css you have to disable the float because with float `text-align:center` and `margin:0 auto` doesn't work. Look at below css

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
/*---Copy Right ---*/
#copyright {
    font-size: .9em;
  text-align: center;
}
#copyright_left {
    text-align: center;
    float:none;
}
#copyright_right {
    text-align: center;
    float:none;
}
}
```

Comment: Does `float: none` take away margin or height? I now get a white space above this section.

Comment: no `float:none` does not effect margin or height there must be some other problem can u please share screenshot or fiddle to figure it out

Comment: Photos added to my question.

Comment: well its working perfectly with the code you shared to me there might be some margin in div on top or may be some float clearing problem...it would be nice if you can share a fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106971/discussion-between-gaurav-aggarwal-and-becky).

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are missing to set yout floats to none. If it still is not centered, try to lookup for any other css which is overwriting your media query declarations.

Edit: the same goes for you margins.

Comment: It is crazy how  miss such simple things when I am this tired. For some reason that brought the div down a bit. Any idea why?

Comment: Floating elements change the way elements are laid out. Yout br element is no longer clearing floats, cause there is none. That could be the cause.